# Send parameters using RNFetchBlob.fetch

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I am trying to send data to a POST api but I can't figure out what's the correct syntax, I am using this:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
    'POST',
    'htttp://www.myserver.com/api/login',
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.json());
})
```

Any help please?

Comment: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Fetch-API#bodystring--arrayobject-optional

Answer (score 2):

import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
            'POST',
            'http://www.myserver.com/api/login',
            { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            JSON.stringify({key: value})
        )
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.json());
        })
```

And pass the last params by  JSON.stringify.

Comment: It is better if you explain your answer a little instead of posting just a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to upload the file itself. 
Pass the fourth argument - file in base64
[Library docs](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/Fetch-API#bodystring--arrayobject-optional)

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
    'POST',
    'htttp://www.myserver.com/api/login',
    { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    file
)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.json());
})
```